# Qt Creator link to static library - ignore dynamic

Tags: qt, hyperlink, static, static-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have created a console app in Qt Creator (Qt5), which uses a third party library.  The library ships with .so and .a and .la files.

I compiled my app no problem and it runs, but when I move it to another Linux box the app complains about the missing .so file.  (So obviously it didn't link with the .a as I expected)

Is there a way to force Qt Creator (.pro file) to link against the static library even if a .so is present?

Comment: Which commands are you using to link your libraries?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to dynamic link to .so, you have to export your path, like

```
PATH=/pathofyourapp:$PATH
export PATH
```

more information please [click here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-x11.html).

if you want to static link to your lib, first you have to have static lib, and link it as normal `-L... -l...` when you compile, but based on your example, I don't think you have static lib.

Comment: I have the static lib file (.a) as well as dynamic (.so), but Qt Creator's make file is just not linking to the.a